# Java StackOverflow error when building a project

Tags: java

I am having a hard time trying to compile a very large .class file via my IDE (Netbeans). The IDE throws StackOverflow error and states that the system is running out of resources.

None of the following worked:

1. Change Netbeans netbeans_default_options in etc folder to this: `"-J-XX:+UseStringDeduplication -J-Xss4m -J-Xms1024m -J-Xmx2048m -J-Djdk.gtk.version=2.2 -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dplugin.manager.check.updates=false -J-Dnetbeans.extbrowser.manual_chrome_plugin_install=yes -J--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-modules=jdk.jshell -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.javadoc/com.sun.tools.javadoc.main=ALL-UNNAMED -J-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions"`
2. Configure Java through java control panel:
   [image]

3. Trying to set via CMD and compile the .class file manually with javac. I run this: `set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xss4m`, but still it doesn't work.

The only thing that did work was invoking directly javac and passing directly the -J-Xss4m option, like so:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\javac.exe" -J-Xss4m C:\Users\asd\Desktop\MyClass.java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently maven got into the way, in fact i was able to get the project to compile by setting an environment variable regarding maven

```
MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Xss4m
```